# how to show one not null value and then all nulls

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a mysql query

```
SELECT 
    unicitem,
    unicreplacement,
    sc_products.productID,
    sc_products.brief_description_ru,
    sc_products.name_ru,
    price.postavchik as suupplier,
    sc_group_discounts.`action`,
    sc_group_discounts.procent,
    price.Price as Price,
    price.in_stock,
    price.supplier
FROM sc_products
LEFT OUTER JOIN t26_replaceable_items ON (sc_products.unic = t26_replaceable_items.unicreplacement)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_group_discounts ON (sc_products.item_group = sc_group_discounts.item_group)
LEFT JOIN price ON (t26_replaceable_items.unicreplacement = price.unic) AND (sc_products.suupplier=price.postavchik)     
WHERE t26_replaceable_items.unicitem = '0092S40050'
GROUP BY productID
ORDER by isnull (price.Price),price.Price ASC
```

I just want to show first row where price is not null and then all the null rows for price. I have no idea how to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this, try it please, hope I did not mistook your willing;)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        unicitem,
        unicreplacement,
        sc_products.productID,
        sc_products.brief_description_ru,
        sc_products.name_ru,
        price.postavchik as suupplier,
        sc_group_discounts.`action`,
        sc_group_discounts.procent,
        price.Price as Price,
        price.in_stock,
        price.supplier
        , @rowno:=@rowno + 1 AS rowno
    FROM sc_products
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t26_replaceable_items ON (sc_products.unic = t26_replaceable_items.unicreplacement)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_group_discounts ON (sc_products.item_group = sc_group_discounts.item_group)
    LEFT JOIN price ON (t26_replaceable_items.unicreplacement = price.unic) AND (sc_products.suupplier=price.postavchik)
    , (SELECT @rowno:=0) tmp   
    WHERE t26_replaceable_items.unicitem = '0092S40050'
    GROUP BY productID
    ORDER by isnull (price.Price),price.Price ASC
) t
WHERE rowno = 1 AND Price IS NOT NULL OR (rowno <> 1 AND Price IS NULL)
```

If price is all null, this query will not work.